# Unable to ssh into ec2 instance with .pem keypair

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, amazon-ec2

I created a new temporary ec2 instance (using a snapshot of my original ec2 instance) ang generated a `mykeypair.pem` file to use as a keypair that I hoped would allow me to connect to my virtual machine in order to make some file changes. (I generated ssh keys on a new laptop and therefore need to connect to my ec2 instance to add the updated public key to `authorized_keys` so that I can access my original ec2 instance. *I am unable to access my old ssh private key*)

With `mykeypair.pem` moved to `~/.ssh/mykeypair.pem`, I ran

```
$ ssh -v  -i "mykeypair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

in `/Users/me/.ssh`.
The result was...

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file mykeypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file mykeypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<redacted>
debug1: Host 'ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:<redacted>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:<redacted>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:<redacted>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:<redacted> 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: mykeypair.pem
debug1: identity added to agent: mykeypair.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem
debug1: identity added to agent: /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem
Received disconnect from <ip addr> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures for ubuntu
Disconnected from <ip addr> port 22
```

These are my `~/.ssh/config` file contents:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykeypair.pem
```

Running only using the generated keypair (what I assumed the below command is doing)

```
ssh -v -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'  -i "mykeypair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

results in

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file mykeypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file mykeypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<redacted>
debug1: Host 'ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: mykeypair.pem
debug1: identity added to agent: mykeypair.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem
debug1: identity added to agent: /Users/me/.ssh/mykeypair.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@ec2-<ip-addr>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I created the instance with this new generated keypair (see screenshot) at the last step when I launched the ec2 instance.

[image: Screenshot of how I created the keypair]

Why isn't this working/what do I need to do to fix it?

Edit: changing the username to `ec2-user@ec2-...` or `bitmani@ec2-...` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described should work. The only thing I can think of is your using the wrong pem file, IP address, or something.

What I would recommend doing is:

- Generate a new keypair on your computer.
- Starting a fresh instance with that key pair.
- Make sure you can log in

  - If you cant, use the out of band browser based connection to connect to the instance.
  - Drop your new key in "authorized_keys"
  - Delete the old keys
- Snapshot the new instance.

## Specific Steps

### Generating Keypair

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519`
It's going to ask you what name you want to save it under. Make sure you're not overwriting something else. It's going to generate a  and .pub.

Aside: What is `-t ed25519`? There are different public key encryption schemes. RSA is one, eliptic curve is another. This particular key type is faster, smaller, more cryptographically secure -- just all around better in almost every way than RSA. The only problem is some stuff doesn't support it. AWS supports it though so your good.

### Importing the public key into AWS

1. Under the EC2 pages, on the left, you'll see a page under "Network & Security" that says "Key Pairs". Click there.
   [image: The left pane on AWS console with "Key Pairs" selected]
2. Now go to "Actions" -> "Import Key"
3. Give it a good name. Import the .pub file.

### Starting an instance using your keys

When you go through the flow of starting an instance, when you click Launch, it pulls up a window that asks what keys you want in the instance. From the dropdown select your new keys.

### Oh no! It still doesn't work!

Olright the next step is making a connection another way and manually putting the ssh keys in there.

### How to connect from the browser

1. In the "Instances" tab, select your instance then go to "Actions" -> "Connect"
2. In the next page, don't change anything, just hit "Connect". Now you should be at a terminal.

### How to add ssh keys to authorized_keys file.

1. I'm assuming you know how to use vim or nano or `echo "stuf" >> file`.
2. Append the contents of your .pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on a new line. Save
3. Profit

Comment: If it isn't a bother, would you be willing to write out detailed steps? I don't want there to be any room for mistakes in my new setup!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by not launching the temporary ec2 instance with the snapshot of my original ebs volume (which I had done in the web ec2 creation ui). I instead created the temporary ec2 instance with the default volume and then attached the snapshot of my volume once the instance was launched. After this, I was able to ssh with the keypair that aws created when I launched the instance.